# Solving a system of equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations

> How to solve
> $$
> \begin{cases}
>  abc=xyz\\
>  a+b+c=x+y+z\\
>  ab+bc+ac=xy+yz+xz\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> ?

We have
$$
ab+bc+ac=xy+yz+xz\implies abc+bc^2+ac^2=c(xy+yz+xz)
$$
and
$$
a+b+c=x+y+z\implies ac^2+bc^2+c^3=c^2(xy+yz+xz)
$$
So
$$
xyz-c^3 = c(xy+yz+xz)-c^2(xy+yz+xz).
$$
But this is too difficult, could you please give me a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that there are two cubic monic polynomials $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ each having the roots $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$ respectively. By Vieta's formulas we know that the coefficients of the two polynomials are equal and hence the roots are the same. So the only solutions come from $$\{a,b,c\}=\{x,y,z\}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Many thanks!